# unhandeled lockdown error(-15) when I try to connect my iphone 4s

Tags: mount, iphone, ipod

Could anyone please help me ?? when I try to connect my iphone 4s I get this message :unhandeled lockdown error(-15) .
It worked just fine so far and I have no idea how to fix it .

Answer (score 6):

Lines in `code` need to be typed into terminal.

1. `sudo apt-get install ifuse libimobiledevice-utils`
2. Unlock iDevice from device's lock screen, plug it in
3. `idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair`
4. Unplug the iDevice
5. Make sure the lock screen is still unlocked
6. Plug it back in

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu uses [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/), a software library which handles iPod, iPad and iPhone devices. iPhone 4S comes with iOS 5. The version of libimobiledevice that ships with Ubuntu id not support devices running iOS 5, however there have been an update released.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/795475
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/882039

Run `ideviceinfo -d` to see if your phone shows up.

Answer (score 1):

another right procedure to avoid the message error "Unable to mount IPhone"

press simultaneously [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[T] //open terminal

type ----> sudo apt-get install ifuse libimobiledevice-utils

insert your password , then Unlock iPhone from slide's lock , plug it in to usb port.

type now into terminal ---> idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair

Unplug the iPhone

pain attention check if your Iphone have screen still unlocked

plug it in to usb port. and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me. http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11350062&postcount=2

First you need to install fuse http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tag/install-ifuse-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Also, if it worked in the first place, but then you reset the iPhone (used Erase all Content and Settings option in the Reset menu in Settings) and it stopped mounting, then the solution is to remove the **~/.config/libimobiledevice/** directory and then replug your iPhone.