# Mount iOS device: unhandled lockdown error

Tags: usb, mount, iphone, ipad, ios

This question has been asked before, but the solutions provided didn't work. Maybe they are outdated and this will be useful to other users too.

I have Ubuntu 18.10 and an iPad 2018 with iOS 12.1.

I'd like to easily transfer files like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151584/how-to-copy-existing-movie-files-on-ipad-to-watch). However when I click on "Documents on My iPad" I get an error

```
Unable to access Documents on My iPad // Unhandled lockdown error (-2)
```

I've tried solutions such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74473/unhandeled-lockdown-error-15-when-i-try-to-connect-my-iphone-4s), but when I do `idevicepair pair` I get an error:

```
ERROR: Device 00008027001E70423A22002E returned unhandled error code -5
```

I also tried, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165939/ubuntu-14-04-ios-8-0-2-unhandled-lockdown-error),

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/lockdown
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/lockdown
```

But that it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I've been waiting for someone to answer with first hand experience. As no one has I'll post an answer with what I've discovered.

[iOS 11 ideviceinstaller, ideviceinfo not working #510](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/510):

- This is a very long support thread with many contributors
- General agreement is need to recompile `idevice.c`
- A patch has been created [here](https://gist.github.com/nikias/b351bf633d62703e0ff4f2fee9628401)

I'm using Android so cannot test how Apple works.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this patch has been committed to the main branch of libimobiledevice a while back: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/commit/5a85432719fb3d18027d528f87d2a44b76fd3e12

Comment: Also in the many messages there they mention having to use `idevicepair` with the `-d` (debug) switch to make it work.